# I tried findByIdAndUpdate markdown I can't update it. can you guide me

Tags: node.js, mongodb, markdown

I built to create sanitizedHtml with post
But I can't update it. What should I do?

When I try to update the description part updates but the sanitizedHtml does not update.

And I tried many ways, I think it might be a problem with findByIdAndUpdate.

or the problem comes from sanitizedHtml

models:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const marked = require('marked');
const html = marked.parse('# Marked in Node.js\n\nRendered by **marked**.');
const createDomPurify = require('dompurify');
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const dompurify = createDomPurify(new JSDOM().window);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Reviewofdharma = require('../models/reviewofdharma');


const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    url: String,
    filename: String
});

ImageSchema.virtual('thumbnail').get(function() {
    return this.url.replace('/upload', '/upload/w_200');
});

const opts = { toJSON: { virtuals: true } }

const DharmaSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true        
    },
    images: [ImageSchema],
    // geometry: {
    //     type: {
    //       type: String,
    //       enum: ['Point'],          
    //       required: true
    //     },
    //     coordinates: {
    //       type: [Number],
    //       required: true
    //     }
    // },
    price: String,
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location: String,
    sanitizedHtml: {
        type: String,
        required: true,        
    },
    sanitizedHtml: marked(values.body),
    // createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    reviewofdharmas: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Reviewofdharma'
        }
    ]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    },
    
opts )

DharmaSchema.virtual('properties.popUpMarkup').get(function() {
    return `
    <strong><a href="/dharmas/${this._id}">${this.title}</a><strong>
    <p>${this.description.substring(0, 50)}...</p>`
});

DharmaSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function(doc){
    if(doc){
        await Reviewofdharma.deleteMany({
            _id: {
                $in: doc.reviewofdharmas
            }
        })
    }
})

DharmaSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if (this.description) {
        this.sanitizedHtml = dompurify.sanitize(marked.parse(this.description))
    }
    next()
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('Dharma', DharmaSchema);
```

routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dharmas = require('../controllers/dharmas')
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const { isLoggedIn2, validateDharma 
} = require('../middleware');
const multer = require('multer')
const { storage } = require('../cloudinary/dharma');
const upload = multer({ storage })

const ExpressError = require('../utils/ExpressError');
const Dharma = require('../models/dharma');

router.route('/')
    .get(catchAsync(dharmas.index))
    .post(
        isLoggedIn2, 
        upload.array('image'), 
        validateDharma, 
        catchAsync(dharmas.createDharma))
    // .post((dharmas.createDharma2))

router.get('/new', isLoggedIn2, dharmas.renderNewForm)

router.route('/:id')
    .get(catchAsync(dharmas.showDharma))
    .put(isLoggedIn2, upload.array('image'), validateDharma, catchAsync(dharmas.updateDharma))
    .delete(isLoggedIn2, catchAsync(dharmas.deleteDharma))

router.get('/:id/edit', isLoggedIn2, catchAsync(dharmas.renderEditForm))



module.exports = router;
```

controllers:

```
const Dharma = require('../models/dharma');
// const mbxGeocoding = require('@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding');
const mapBoxToken = process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN;
// const geocoder = mbxGeocoding({ accessToken: mapBoxToken });
const { cloudinary } = require('../cloudinary/dharma');


module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {
    const dharmas = await Dharma.find({}).sort({
        createdAt: 'desc'
    })
    res.render('dharmas/homeV2', { dharmas })
}

module.exports.renderNewForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('dharmas/new');
}

module.exports.createDharma = async(req, res, next) => {
    // const geoData = await geocoder.forwardGeocode({
    //     query: req.body.dharma.location,
    //     limit: 1
    // }).send()
    const dharma = new Dharma(req.body.dharma);
    // dharma.geometry = geoData.body.features[0].geometry;
    dharma.images = req.files.map(f => ({ url: f.path, filename: f.filename }));
    dharma.author = req.user._id;
    await dharma.save();
    console.log(dharma);
    req.flash('infoDharma', 'โพสต์สำเร็จ');
    res.redirect(`${dharma._id}`)
}

// module.exports.createDharma2 = async (req, res) => {
//     const dharma = new Dharma({
//         title: req.body.title,
//         description: req.body.description
//     })
//     try {
//         dharma = await dharma.save()
//         res.redirect(`${dharma.id}`)
//     } catch (e) {
//         res.render(`${dharma.id}`, { dharma })
//     }
// }

module.exports.showDharma = async (req, res) => {
    const dharma = await Dharma.findById(req.params.id).populate('reviewofdharmas').populate('author');
    if(!dharma){
        req.flash('error', 'ไม่พบข้อมูล');
        return res.redirect('/dharmas');
    }
    console.log(dharma);
    res.render('dharmas/show', { dharma });
}

module.exports.renderEditForm = async (req, res) => {
    const dharma = await Dharma.findById(req.params.id)
    if(!dharma){
        req.flash('error', 'ไม่พบข้อมูล');
        return res.redirect('/dharmas');
    }
    res.render('dharmas/edit', { dharma });
}

module.exports.updateDharma = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    console.log(req.body);
    const dharma = await Dharma.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.dharma });
    const imgs = req.files.map(f => ({ url: f.path, filename: f.filename }));
    dharma.images.push(...imgs);
    await dharma.save()
    if(req.body.deleteImages){
        for(let filename of req.body.deleteImages){
            await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(filename);
        }
        await dharma.updateOne({ $pull: { images: {filename: { $in: req.body.deleteImages } } } } )
    }
    req.flash('infoDharma', 'อัปเดตสำเร็จ');
    res.redirect(`${dharma._id}`)
}

module.exports.deleteDharma = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    await Dharma.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    req.flash('infoDharma', 'ลบโพสต์สำเร็จ');
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `{ new: true }` flag to return the updated object:

```
const dharma = await Dharma.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    { ...req.body.dharma },
    { new: true }
  );
```

With that you should be able to run the following `dharma.images.push(...imgs)` statement.